# Ubuntu 19.10 Stellarium telescope control

Tags: usb, 19.10

I am having a new hand controller delivered, I'll post the results later.

I am new to Ubuntu, so I am seeking help with Stellarium and Telescope Control.

I have rigorously followed the guide mentioned [here](https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/stellarium-and-a-telescope). I have set up my telescope in the 'Telescope Control' script, and selected the correct port: ttyUSB0 and selected my mount. However, it will not connect.

I have set up 'dialout'

`id -Gn`   returns what I think is the correct response:-

```
phil adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

dmesg | grep FTDI

returns:-

```
[    2.895897] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[   16.240250] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[   16.240327] ftdi_sio 3-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   16.253003] usb 3-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I tried re-booting, however, this made no difference.

I am at a loss for what to do. Can anyone assist please?

Comment: ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0  returns:- crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jan 13 13:31 /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: According to `id -Gn` you have no group `dialout`, wheras from your `ls` command in the comments there is a `dialout` group and it owns `ttyUSB0`. Please check.

Comment: It's also helpful to know which version/flavour of Ubuntu is used, as well as the release number.

Comment: All I know is that it is version 19.10, I don't know how to find out what flavour it is. This is all very new to me, so please forgive my ignorance. It is the desktop version though.

Answer (score 3):

You're NOT in the `dialout` group, (`phil adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare`), so you have "other" access to

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jan 13 13:31 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

that is, `---`, or NO access.

To put yourself in the `dialout` group, you must do two steps:

First, update your `group` membership with:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

Then, start a new process with one of `newgrp dialout`, logout/login, reboot.

Comment: Thank you. I ran the command lines that you gave. It appears that we are getting somewhere, in that In Stellarium I can get a connection. Although Stellarium now says 'Connected' I cannot slew the telescope. So, there must still be something missing. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This is what is returned with the ls command:-  phil@phil-Aspire-5551:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jan 13 22:31 /dev/ttyUSB0    Is this correct?

Comment: AskUbuntu only searches, and makes available to future users, the information in the Questions, not the comments. Also, if you have a second question, ask a second Question ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask ). AskUbuntu is a problem-solving site, not a hold-my-hand site.

Answer (score 0):

I now have a replacement HC which connects properly to Stellarium. I can now slew the scope, however, it will only slew to targets in approximately half of the sky; if I try to get it to acquire a target in the problem half of the sky, Stellarium then loses lock, meaning that slewing to a target in the working half of the sky, it points entirely the wrong way. I have equatorial selected, and allow auto flipping in the Synscan HC: this is on my Ubuntu Linux laptop ( it also behaves in the same way on my Windows laptop). Very odd, I can't see how to correct this. Do you think it is a Stellarium or hand controller issue? I have also updated the Synscan to the latest version: 4.39.10, which made no difference. Slewing with the HC is not a problem, it does what it is told.