# Serial port unstable operation

Tags: usb, serial-port

I've got a FTDI FT232RL based USB to serial adapter connected to a motor. The operation is unstable on Ubuntu 20.04 using proprietary library ("testapp"). The setup works fine under Windows XP.

```
dmesg | tail
[15165.501972] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[15165.672245] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[15165.672250] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[15165.672253] usb 1-10: Product: XIDC-USB
[15165.672256] usb 1-10: Manufacturer: XIMC
[15165.672259] usb 1-10: SerialNumber: DC000285
[15165.676679] ftdi_sio 1-10:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[15165.676740] usb 1-10: Detected FT232RL
[15165.677483] usb 1-10: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

and

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
```

So, the device is connected, `/dev/ttyUSB0` is created, and `sudo ./testapp` gives "error opening device" 9 of 10 runs, opens the device and prints garbage motor status 1 of 10 runs, and 1 of 50 works fine. So it does works, but *rarely*. I wonder what can be the cause?
I tried to `ssty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 19200` to lower the rate, but nothing changes. There is a similiar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202681/ubuntu-19-10-stellarium-telescope-control), but I'm okay (for now) with sudoing the command. How to find what is wrong? Thank you.

*EDIT #1*:
Found about [hardware flow control](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299430/serial-can-receive-but-cant-send) issues, checked the answer, but

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 --all
speed 19200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 0; time = 10;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo -echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

there is `-crtscts`, so the flow control is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the hardware incompatibility. For whatever reason the chip does not work on *modern* machines, even with MB's having native USB 2.0 ports. I solved it by using an auxiliary USB 2.0 hub (also from XP era) with much shorter USB cable. No idea why modern machines are unable to power the device with long cable when older machines have no problem.

Comment: USB 2 has a lower "available power" than e.g. USB 3. Generally: Lengthy cables should always be avoided, especially with low voltage devices; this is physics, has nothing to do with OS.

Comment: Exactly! I also thought that 3.0 should be more powerful than 2.0 so longer cables are possible. but old USB 2.0 ports work well with whatever cable, and modern USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports are not able to work correctly with long cables.